# How to use async values in Riverpod in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I'm using Riverpod in my app for state management. Here is my code.

Main method-

```
runApp(
      MaterialApp(
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                theme: ThemeProvider.themeOf(themeContext).data,
                home: route.Route(),
              );
            
    );
```

```
class Route extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    AsyncValue<User> auth = watch(authStateChangesProvider);
    return auth.when(
      data: (user) {
        if (user != null && user.uid != null) {
       return HomePage();
        } else {
          return LoginPage();
        }
      }, 
      loading: () => CircularProgressIndicator(),
      error: (e, o) => Text('error'), 
    );
  }
}
```

AuthStateChanges-

```
final firebaseAuthProvider =
    Provider<FirebaseAuth>((ref) => FirebaseAuth.instance);

final StreamProvider<User> authStateChangesProvider = StreamProvider<User>(
    (ref) => ref.watch(firebaseAuthProvider).authStateChanges());
```

I want to show the users an onboarding screen if it's their first time logging in the app. But I don't know how to implement that since i cant use an `async` method in `auth.when()`. How do I do that?

Comment: one thing too, as I'm using riverpod to listen for authstatechanges, i noticed that whenever i hot reload, the stream emits new data (i wrote a print statement just before ```HomePage```). Is this normal or I'm missing something?

Comment: Can you show code for authStateChangesProvider?  Hard to guess what it's doing here.

Comment: I've added please check

Comment: are you receiving error messages in logcat?